# How Prepare the database for SALEOR

Tags: python, django, saleor

Prepare the database for SALEOR:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

This command will need to be able to create database extensions. If you get an error related to the CREATE EXTENSION command please review the notes from the user creation step.

```
# python3 manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 216, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Help me for this ERROR, Please.

Comment: The traceback doesn’t give any hints what the problem is. You’ll need to give some more instructions on how to reproduce the problem, or hope that somebody reading this has seen the same problem with saleor.

Comment: Are you sure you have the SECRET_KEY environment variable set? This looks like a Django stack trace for the case where it's missing.

Answer (score 1):

Setting SECRET_KEY solved this for me.

```
$ export SECRET_KEY='secret key output'
```

One way to generate a secret key:

```
$ python3
>>> import random
>>> ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*(-_=+)') for i in range(50))
'some secret key output appears here'
>>>
```